# How to fetch specific data from XML using C#

Tags: c#, xml, textbox

I'm trying to fetch specific data from a Xml file to display in a textbox. My Xml file name as "test.xml" has following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Body>
    <Context>
        <PageNo>a87</PageNo>
        <Verse>"Do it right"</Verse>
    </Context>
</Body>
```

My C# code is below: Edited to reflect recent chnages

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.ComponentModel;
   using System.Data;
   using System.Drawing;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using System.Windows.Forms;
   using System.Xml;

   namespace learn2
   {
     public partial class Form1 : Form
     {
       public Form1()
       {
         InitializeComponent();
       }

       private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
         pageid1();
       }

           private void pageid1()
    {
    textBox1.Clear();
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();         
    doc.Load("C:\\test.xml"); 

    var pagenoNodeList = doc.SelectNodes("Body/Context/PageNo");
    var pageNoNode = pagenoNodeList[0]; // To select the first node
    var text = pageNoNode.InnerText;    // Gets the text value inside the node
    textBox1.Text = text;
}       }
  }
```

I highly appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Try `textBox1.Text = pageno[0].InnerText;`

Comment: Its giving me the following error:
Error CS1061 'Form1' does not contain a definition for 'textBox1_TextChanged' and no extension method 'textBox1_TextChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'Form1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Sounds like you added an event handler for `TextChanged` and then you must have removed it at some point. Check in `Form1.Designer.cs` for something like `this.textBox1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_TextChanged);` and remove that line

Comment: Bassie, I commented the line and compile the code without any success.

Comment: You should post all of the code which doesn't work as well as the entire error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to identify the node you are looking for, as `SelectNodes` returns a [`System.Xml.XmlNodeList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae(v=vs.110).aspx), and then get the value of `InnerText`:

```
var pagenoNodeList = doc.SelectNodes("Body/Context/PageNo");
var pageNoNode = pagenoNodeList[0]; // To select the first node
var text = pageNoNode.InnerText;    // Gets the text value inside the node
textBox1.Text = text;
```

Comment: Bassie, I changed my code in pageid1 method based on your suggestion still it does fetch the page id from the Xml file. edited pageid1 method is below.

Comment: @shapedworld I don't know what you mean - your code is still the same

Comment: private void pageid1()
        {
        textBox1.Clear();
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();         
        doc.Load("C:\\test.xml"); 

        var pagenoNodeList = doc.SelectNodes("Body/Context/PageNo");
        var pageNoNode = pagenoNodeList[0]; // To select the first node
        var text = pageNoNode.InnerText;    // Gets the text value inside the node
        textBox1.Text = text;
    }

Comment: I changed my code in first questions to represent the edits i did

Comment: What appears in the textbox?

Comment: It's giving me an error pointing to the following line" Application.Run(new Form1());" : ERROR: XmlExceptions Unhandled

Comment: @shapedworld you need to post the entire error message as well as the code which is not working in your question or it will be impossible to help

Comment: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: There are multiple root elements. Line 7, position 3."

Error is on a popup window pointing at  
         doc.Load("C:\\test.xml"); // Loading the xml document to "doc"

Comment: I wish I could just screencap the desktop

Comment: Bassie, I was missing a semicolon. Everything is working now. Thanks.